# Boto3 get InvalidClientTokenId when using update_service_specific_credential

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam

I want to change Git credential for AWS CodeCommit to Active/Inactive using Boto3.

I tried to use `update_service_specific_credential` but I got this error:

```
An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the CreateServiceSpecificCredential operation: The security token included in the request is invalid: ClientError
```

**My code:**

```
iamClient = boto3.client('iam')

response=iamClient.update_service_specific_credential(UserName="****",
ServiceSpecificCredentialId="*****",Status="Active")
```

someone tried to use it?
Any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

AWS errors are often purposefully opaque/non-specific so could you give a bit more detail? Specifically, are the user performing the update and the user whose credentials are being updated two different users? There may be a race condition arising if the user being updated IS the user performing the update.